# Can logical replication be stopped anytime I want?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-data-wrapper, logical-replication

I have two databases in different servers and data streaming from one server (X database) to another server (Y database) with the help of logical replication.

My question is the following: is there any way to stop logical replication any time I want (for example for 20 minutes) and then enable it again? Or maybe switch between logical replication and foreign data wrapper. I want to do this over the website I have built.

Comment: How are you using the foreign data wrapper?

Comment: I am using two replication one of them is foreign data wrapper another is logical replication. I will try to explain what I have done. Consider I have 10 tables and based on these tables I have built 10 views in one database (X) and built foreign data wrapper there . And in another server I have built foreign tables that is capturing all the changes from X database and update views (same views are also actual in Y database ) then Using Bi tool I am joining and visualizing these views. That is the flow. Now I want to build a mechanism to stop it from my website and only use logical replication

Comment: In another word to switch between foreign data wrapper and logical replication

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean by "*built foreign data wrapper there*" (in X), "*built foreign tables that is capturing all the changes*", and "*update views (same views are also actual in Y database)*"

Comment: You can have both logical replication and FDW in use at the same time.  You can swap between them by, for example, changing your search_path.  But isn't clear how this could accomplish your goal, or indeed what your goal is.  This seems like an XY problem.

Comment: Yes exactly I am using both FDW and logical replication at the same time. Problem is that I am also required to swap between them from my website. Both of them are bringing data from database to DWH in which there are both logical and FDW working in different schemas. I want sometimes to stop FDW and let only logical replication work. I know it is not maybe best practice or useless but must be done.

Comment: @AlisahibQadimov Why do you have that requirement? What problem does swapping between them solve?

Comment: @AlisahibQadimov Still not clear how FDW "*brings data from database to DWH*" or how it "*is capturing all the changes*". Did you set up some automated process that uses a FDW connection to copy data into warehouse tables? Or do you just have some foreign tables (and views over them) set up that lets you directly query the source database from the warehouse? If the latter, then "stopping" the FDW connection will simply make all queries accessing those tables throw an error.

Answer (score 3):

You can pause logical replication with

```
ALTER SUBSCRIPTION name DISABLE;
```

and resume it with

```
ALTER SUBSCRIPTION name ENABLE;
```

While replication is disabled, the replication slot on the publisher makes the publisher retain all the WAL that is necessary for the subscriber to catch up, and the subscriber will do so automatically when you enable the subscription again. The danger is not that the subscriber can lose data, but that the publisher's disk can run full if the subscription is disabled for too long.